# Binning by equal standard deviation R

Tags: r, vector, binning

I have a vector containing some data, in particular

```
tau_3[p_3<3]
 [1]  7.837  7.813  6.276  8.669  7.001  6.032  6.897  5.967  9.417  8.251  7.892  8.752  9.873  9.461  8.591  7.697  8.372  9.324  9.135  7.807
[21] 10.034 10.701  9.315  6.979  9.843  8.742  8.829  7.406  8.588  6.803  7.462  8.379  8.075  8.294  8.218
```

which has to be studied with respect to another set of datapoints

```
>p_3[p_3<3]
 [1] 0.020 0.021 0.022 0.023 0.024 0.026 0.028 0.014 0.029 0.030 0.033 0.035 0.037 0.040 0.042 0.044 0.050 0.055 0.060 0.065 0.070 0.075 0.080 0.085
[25] 0.090 0.100 0.110 0.120 0.130 0.150 0.160 0.190 0.200 0.230 0.240
```

[image: plot]

I would like to divide the pressure p_3 data (the subset given above) it in such a way that each bin has, more or less, the same standard deviation for the decay time \tau_3 data that it contains. In particular, I should have a vector containing the breaks for such binned data.

I don't know of any package that could do this and I've been scratching my head on how to do it for hours. If you could give me a solution I would be very grateful.

Comment: How many bins? Should there be no overlap?

Comment: @AllanCameron The number of bins is not important and yes, there should be no overlap! I think that it's not possible to have exactly the same standard deviation, but should only be roughly the same.

Comment: But what does "roughly the same" mean? If you just cut the vector numerically into 7 bins, then 4 of them have exactly the same std dev, and the overall range is between 0.007 and 0.012. This is already pretty close for a collection of length-5 vectors.

Comment: @AllanCameron Oh I'm very sorry, let me edit my question, I didn't explain well on what data the sd is to be calculated.